# Django Queryset Construction

Tags: django

Assuming my models are as below, how would I write one query that filters on derived data about the models?  In this example, I would like to pull "All pages in Times New Roman that are part of books with exactly ten pages and all pages not in Comic Sans."  Do I need multiple queries (filter books with these attributes and use __in for a second filter) or to denormalize my database?  Ideally these models could get quite big and I want speedy lookups on these derived quantities, so I think denormalization might be my best bet.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField()

class Page(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    font = models.Charfield()
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

Comment: I think you are missing the relation beetwen the two models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I presume that there is a foreign key relationship between `Page` and `Book` as a page belong in a book.

```
class Page(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    font = models.Charfield()
```

Without modify your database significantly, it's probably easiest to break this into two queries.  The first part is to generate a list of books that have 10 pages and do not have Comic Sans.  You can use the [reverse lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) on the FK relationship between `Page` and `Book`.  Also you'll need to [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the page numbers.

```
book_list = Book.objects.exclude(page__font="Comic Sans").annotate(page_count=Count('page')).filter(page_count=10)
```

The last part of your query is fairly straightforward.

```
page_query_set = Page.objects.filter(font="Times New Roman").filter(book__in=book_list)
```

If this is running slowly, you can reduce the amount of processing it takes by just duplicating data in the Books model so you aren't counting pages each time you are making a query.  If each book has only one font, you probably can duplicate this in the book model to save time as well.

However, I'd recommend to keep it simple at first and optimize only when you need to and it starts to slow down.  There might be a better way to approach it depending on how it's being used.